# lucene index and search is not working child to parent

Tags: spring, lucene, hibernate-search

Class A is root entity and Class B is child entity with relationship 1:n.

My sample code:

```
@Entity
@Index
Class A {

 @javax.persistence.Id
 @DocumentId
 @Column
 private Long id;

 @IndexedEmbedded
 private List<B> elements;
}

@Entity
@Index
Class B {

 @javax.persistence.Id
 @DocumentId
 @Column
 private Long id;

 @Column
 private Long name;

 @IndexedEmbedded
 private A a;
}
```

My lucene query:

```
QueryBuilder builder = searchFactory.buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(B.class).get();
PhraseContext phraseCtx = builder.phrase().withSlop(2).boostedTo(25f);
PhraseMatchingContext phraseMatchingCtx = phraseCtx.onField("name");
Query query =  builder.all().createQuery();

FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query,B.class);
List<B> list = fullTextQuery.getResultList();
```

But it does not retrieved the results.

Comment: What does "does not retrieved the results" mean? Doesn't it return? Throws an exception? Returns null? Returns an empty List? Returns a list with empty instances or nulls? Also what data do you store? What data do you expect it to return?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `@IndexedEmbedded` with `@ContainedIn` annotation on B's side of the relationship.

Lets say A is the parent of B, then in B you should add the contained in annotation:

```
@ContainedIn 
private A a;
```

Dont forget the OneToMany/ManyToOne mappings